# Java sorting map<String,String> by String prefix

Tags: java, list, sorting, dictionary, treemap

In Java.
How do I sort a map by given string with numeric prefix.
I get the map from properties file:

```
1_aaa=bla1
2_bbb=bla2
3_ccc=bla3
4_ddd=bla4 
...
10_jjj=bla10
11_kkk=bla11
12_lll=bla12
```

I am loading the properties from file:

```
FileInputStream is =new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(is);
```

and after:
`SortedMap<Object, Object> sortedProperties new TreeMap<Object, Object>(prop);`

Now when using TreeMap --> '10_jjj' is the first element in the SortedMap
and I want '1_aaa' to be the first.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior is because [`0` comes before `_` in the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

To get want you want, write your [`Comparator<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and compare the Strings base on the prefix, then use the [`TreeMap(Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29) constructor to construct the map.

A simple sample without any error checking, etc.:

```
class Cmp implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return prefixNum(a) - prefixNum(b);
    }

    private int prefixNum(String a) {
        return Integer.parseInt(a.split("_")[0]);
    }
}
```

Then instantiate the map like this:

```
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(new Cmp());
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own `Comparator` to acomplish this.

During creation of the `TreeMap` you can give this `Comparator` to the `Map` and then it is sorted the way you implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert the prefixes into integers and then sort on them, e.g.

```
int prefix = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, str.indexOf("_"))); // sort/compare on this
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
class ComparatorOfNumericString implements Comparator<String>{

    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String a[] = o1.split("_");
        String b[] = o2.split("_");
        return Integer.parseInt(a[0])-Integer.parseInt(b[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("1_aaa", "blah");
    p.setProperty("10_aaa", "blah");

    Comparator<Object> c = new Comparator<Object>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
            String s1 = (String)o1;
            String s2 = (String)o2;

            Integer i1 = Integer.valueOf(s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf('_')));
            Integer i2 = Integer.valueOf(s2.substring(0, s2.indexOf('_')));

            return i1.compareTo(i2);
        }
    };

    SortedMap<Object, Object> sortedProperties = new TreeMap<Object, Object>(c);
    sortedProperties.putAll(p);

    System.out.println(sortedProperties.firstKey());
```